# Mnemonic seed creation in "pseudo code"

Tags: mnemonic-seed

I would like to know exactly what is going on behind the process of creating the mnemonic seed from the string of bits.
For example I don't understand why in the vocabulary is only around 1624 words, I would expects full 11 bit scope (I suppose that bit string is divided into 11-bit parts and each is parsed with appropriate word).. 
Maybe I have wrong vocabulary, in this case please point me somewhere.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know exactly what is going on behind the process of creating the mnemonic seed from the string of bits.

The whole process is explained here:

[How are monero wallets generated?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/468/how-are-monero-wallets-generated)

> For example I don't understand why in the vocabulary is only around 1624 words, I would expects full 11 bit scope (I suppose that bit string is divided into 11-bit parts and each is parsed with appropriate word)

It's 1626 words, and a mnemonic of 24 words gives 1626^24 combinations which is slightly above 2^256.

The conversion is done in triplets where each triplet is 32 bits of information:, ie `8 * 1626^3 = 8 * 2^32.0013 = 2^256.01`

It's really a conversion between a base1626 number and a base16 number (or backwards), where each word can be though of as a label for some number between 0 and 1625.